# Keras Callback Request Additional Tensors

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback, deep-learning

Tensorflow Hooks allow to request additional Tensors:

```
class MyHook(tf.estimator.SessionRunHook):

    def before_run(self, run_context):

         request_fetches = {"my_tensor": tensor}

         return tf.estimator.SessionRunArgs(request_fetches)

    def after_run(self, run_context, run_values):
         print(run_values.results["my_tensor"])
```

How can I execute a similar objective using Keras Callbacks ?

I use a simple `model.compile().fit()` strategy

Comment: What is the tensor you want to access and evaluate in a Keras callback? For example, is it the weights of a specific layer of the Keras model?

Comment: I'm looking for  `<tf.Tensor 'current_loss_scale/Read/ReadVariableOp:0' shape=() dtype=float32>` which is set when you use Automatic Mixed Precision.

You could also think about a case where I have an expensive metric to compute. I could use `metric` in `model.compile()` but it would compute the metric every steps. And I would like to compute the metric once every N steps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested to evaluate a tensor in a callback, you should be able to use [`keras.backend.eval()`](https://keras.io/backend/#eval) in any methods of that callback (e.g. `on_train_begin()`, `on_epoch_end()`, etc.).

Further, you can also access the model object in a custom Keras callback using `self.model` attribute, so you should be able to give it some data and get its output in return (i.e. using `self.model.predict()`), or access the weights of its layers (i.e. using `self.model.layers` which is the list of layers in the model).

Additionally, you can create a custom backend function using [`keras.backend.function()`](https://keras.io/backend/#function) and run it in the custom callback you define.